# My friend's guitar broke. How can I get it repaired?

Tags: electric-guitar

My friend broke his guitar. It fell down and it broke near the tone control.

Can I in any way get it repaired?
Here's a photo.[image]

Comment: Take it to a repair shop. At best it needs a new scratch-plate; we cannot tell any more from a photograph.

Answer (score 5):

At worst it'll need a new plastic scratchplate, which you could source, cut out, drill out for the pots and switch and screw holes.Or buy the correct replacement - quite available if it's a Strat, or Stratalike Not a difficult job for an inexperienced diyer, as it's only unscrewing - no soldering.

However, if you have all the bits, superglue would be a good move. Take the tone pot out first, though. It's all got to be unscrewed first. As a cheap and cheerful repair, a thin plastic or metal (aluminium?) plate could be fashioned to go under the tone pot position, and would hold in place with a couple of little screws.

Comment: in 3d art classes, we used to buy a bunch of super cheap "for sale by owner signs" from the local hardware store, laminate them (glue them together), and then cut them to shape or heat-form them. Might be useful for this purpose. Then again,: mail-order a new one